# Mongo shell : is there a way to execute the javascript code remotely instead of doing work in the local machine?

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a MongoDB instance running on Mongo Atlas and I have a local machine.

I want to execute a script but I would like this script to be execute on the **mongo instance**.

I have tried several things like Robo3T or Mongo shell. And it looks like the behaviour is not the one I want.

Suppose we have this script :

```
print(db.users.find({}).toArray().length);
```

My users collection has around 30k rows. I voluntarily use toArray() to force the creation of a js array. But I want this array to be created... In the MongoDB instance or close to it ; not on the instance where I launched the mongo shell (or Robo3T).

This is obviously not my use case to count the number of users, if I really just wanted the number of users, I would have used .count() and it would have been faster. But I just want to illustrate the fact that the code is run not at the location I want it to be run.

Suppose you connect to a remote ssh. You have a very poor connection.
If you do something like

```
wget http://moviedatabase.com/rocky.mp4
```

which is a 1 To movie.
You will take the same time if your connection is blazing fast or amazingly slow : what counts is the bandwith of the server you are connecting to.

With my example, all depends on the connection of the instance you are launching Mongo shell on.
If it has a good connection, it will be faster than if it has a good connection.

What is the way to execute js code "closer" to the MongoDB instance?
How this behaviour not a problem when you administrate a MongoDB instance?

Thanks in advance,

Jerome

Comment: The script goal is batch processing. Then, you need to run it inside the same network that the mongodb server and ideally in the same server. The results goes to files or collections.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do.

There is no generic context where you can run arbitrary code, but you can [store a javascript function on the server](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/#store-a-javascript-function-on-the-server), which can then be used in [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) or [mapReduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce).

Note that [server-side javascript](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/server-side-javascript/index.html#server-side-javascript) can be disabled with the [security.javascriptEnable](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.javascriptEnabled) configuration parameter.

I would expect that Atlas disables this for it's free and shared tiers.